# how to differentiate between different server sent event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, server-sent-events

I have a application in  which different user listens to server sent event source for a periodical response .I intend to sent response from server with corresponding Id and data in json format.And at client side each client when data arrives checks for matching Id if found it process the data else ignore it.But the flaw in this approach is each user gets data from periodical updates even if it is not intended for them.I read a few articles about sse but could't find anything about this

**My question is  using server side events is there any way of sending response to specific listeners and if so how .?**

Comment: yes, in fact you have to send it to a specific one; broadcast functions simply loop all users and send each one the same message... run your IF on the server before you send, not on the client after it arrives...

Comment: @dandavis how to send it to a specific one using custom events names ?

Comment: I just noticed the tags. Are you asking how to handle the message on the client-side? (Either way, I don't think jquery tag is needed?)

Comment: How to do this is very particular to your server side implementation. So can you elaborate on how what you have it working?

Comment: @baynezy I can provide full skeletal srtucture with code but it will be long

Comment: I don't need the code some idea of the technologies involved. What server-side language are you using to create your Server-Sent Events? How is that notified of new events?

Comment: php is serverside language and I am refreshing the page every few seconds and I will post it in details as answer to this question it would explain all that you asked

Comment: @baynezy with firefox browser the application continues to work for a certain period of time then it stops trying to reconnect to server .No matter what I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was to register the user /ask the user for login and return a unique Identification key.Using this key as event name event listener is initialized in the post back success function of registration/login $post();.

So basically each event listener listen to a unique event .At server side each event name is broadcasted followed by data so unique event listeners get messages only intended for them.

### Clientside

```
$.post( "chatReg.php", { xxx: xxxx, time: xxx}).done(function( data ) {

     if((typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined")&&((localStorage.getItem("uname") !== null))) {
    var source = new EventSource("XXXXXXXX.php");   

    source.addEventListener(localStorage.getItem("uname"), function(e) {
     var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

     $('div.chat-box-content').append('<div class="msgWrapper"><div class="msgwrapperleft"><div class="iconright"><img src="http://placehold.it/40X40"></img></div><div class="MessageRight">'+data.Message+ '</div> </div><p class="ArrivedTimeRight"><span ><span class="timeago" >'+CreateTimestamp()+'</span></span></p></div>');

    }, false);


    } 

}
```

### Server

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header("refresh: 5;");

    echo  'event: '.$row['SpecialId'];
            echo PHP_EOL;

            echo  'data: {"Message":"'.$row['Message'].'","xxxId":"'.$row['xxxId'].'"}';
            echo PHP_EOL;
            echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Why not just use a query string, and in backend filter events? I've implemented in this way u could see a minimal example [here](https://gist.github.com/mirusky-enube/78fc9ca68af913e2f122fc94c6c78a2f

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE** based on question clarification: how to stop a client receiving SSE messages that are not intended for it.

The best way is not to send it. Filter the messages server-side. (As the earlier part of my answer explains, this is easy, because every SSE connection already has a *dedicated* server process deciding what data to send to it.) *This approach is superior in all ways* (CPU/memory, network bandwidth, security, privacy, programmer effort).

The alternative would be to filter it client-side, and there are two ways to do this. One is to be sending json data to the clients. In your `onMessage()` handler use one of those fields to decide if this message is for this client.

The other would be to use the `event:` field of SSE, and then listen for that message:

```
es = new EventSource(...);
es.addEventListener("forUser123", function(e) {
  //Process their data here
  }, false);
```

The `event:forUser123` header would be set on the server, before you send the `data:` field. (BUT, if you have to go that trouble to add an extra header, it is better to filter the messages you send at this point.)

---

**Original Answer**

The thing you want to do (be client-specific) is easy, and the way you thought Server-Sent-Events worked (broadcast) is harder.

Each `EventSource` connection to your server is a dedicated socket. So it comes through just like any other connection to the web server, the only difference is the socket is not closed, but kept open so the server can continue to send data. This also implies there is one dedicated process or thread on the server for dealing with messages to send to that client.

So, the server knows who each user is (assuming they identify themselves, with say a session cookie), and can choose what data to send that client.

**Aside: Why is broadcast harder?** Say you have 100 connected SSE clients - you actually have 100 independent server processes running. To broadcast a single message to all 100, you first have to tell those 100 server-side processes what the message is, so that they can pass it on. You might do this with an upstream socket, or they might regularly poll a "messagesToSendToEveryone" database table to see if anything new has been added.

Comment: Its actually enquiry chat app user without login sends a chat to server .The server periodically checks DB for incoming chats then formulates reply and insert to table for chatlog table  and the sse feed generation page checks for the unviewed message and broadcasts the message each client source analyze the message and if the Id matches appends to chat as reply.And I am asking you how to send data to specific client listener upvoted for your effort

Comment: @SachinDivakar That all sounds the way I'd do it, so I'm not sure what your remaining question is? Once you've polled the DB for messages for your user, you just write the output to stdout.

Comment: Yeah the client side is where server listener listens to event source and when data is received it checks if its correct user.So my question was how to prevent data from being exposed to user at client side

Comment: @SachinDivakar I updated my answer with more explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Again I was thinking along the same lines infact exactly the same way.I had already implemented custom event .First when user registers for chat it returns custom identification Id as response from server .So server broadcasts the result will go to corresponding event listener but this approach landed me in a new problem so I asked this question to figure out if there is any other perpsective

Comment: Bro solved that problem also it was due to distraction that it occurred what actually happenned was I was typing stating what was happenning all of a sudden I realised the blunder I made I and I corrected it placed the checking of uname in document load which resulted it being not registered the first time only on page reload it worked correctly since I was using local storage .I am adding the code to your answer to make it more direct and accepting this as answer

Comment: @SachinDivakar I think your edit needs to go on your question (and/or in a self-answer).

Comment: I thought it would implementation what you said and did you read my edit did you like my approach ??